# SQL - Subquery Error and Sum Error

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

The SQL code I have is shown below. The issue I am having is with the subquery first of all. 
The result displays the error:

> SQL ERROR: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted
>   when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is
>   used as an expression

Need to show rows with date greater than (or equal to) the date where ESource = Detail - The rows need to be summed in some columns and a single value selected in others.

Code used:

```
select DISTINCT 
  A.Policy, 
  A.Fund, 
 (SUM(A.AddUnits)) AS SUM,
 ((C.TotalUnits - (SUM(A.AddUnits))) * A.Price) AS Value, 

Inner JOIN TableC C
ON C.PolicyNumber = A.PolicyNumber 

where A.PolicyNumber = '120' AND C.NumberOfUnits > 0 AND C.InvestmentFund = A.InvestmentFund 

AND A.DateOfEntry < DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())
AND A.DateOfEntry >= (Select DateOfEntry FROM TableA AS D where D.ESource = 'Detail') 
AND A.UnitPrice = (Select UnitPrice FROM TableA AS E where E.ESource = 'Detail')

ORDER BY IH.DateOfEntry DESC
```

Tables are:

Table A:

Policy    Fund    Units    Price     ESource     Date

120         BR       6           0.74        RE          2015

120        BR     -100         0.72     Detail     2014

120        BR     6         0.71           RE        2013

TABLE C:

Policy    Fund    TotalUnits

120         BR       400

DESIRED RESULT:

Policy       Fund            Sum                  Price              Value

120              BR       [6+(-100)] = -94          0.72     [(400+(-94))*0.72] = 220.32

As well as the sub query issues - the command to get `price = 0.72 [where ="Detail"]` is stopping the sum of both rows occurring making `Sum = -100` and not -94

Any help with the errors would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `where` clause:

```
where A.PolicyNumber = '120' AND
      C.NumberOfUnits > 0 AND
      C.InvestmentFund = A.InvestmentFund  AND
      A.DateOfEntry < DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) AND
      A.DateOfEntry >= (Select DateOfEntry FROM TableA AS D where D.ESource = 'Detail') AND
      A.UnitPrice = (Select UnitPrice FROM TableA AS E where E.ESource = 'Detail')
```

The last two clauses are the problem.  One way to fix this is with the keywords `ANY`, `SOME`, or `ALL`:

```
where A.PolicyNumber = '120' AND
      C.NumberOfUnits > 0 AND
      C.InvestmentFund = A.InvestmentFund  AND
      A.DateOfEntry < DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) AND
      A.DateOfEntry >= ALL (Select DateOfEntry FROM TableA AS D where D.ESource = 'Detail') AND
      A.UnitPrice = ALL (Select UnitPrice FROM TableA AS E where E.ESource = 'Detail')
```

However, I prefer explicit aggregation:

```
where A.PolicyNumber = '120' AND
      C.NumberOfUnits > 0 AND
      C.InvestmentFund = A.InvestmentFund  AND
      A.DateOfEntry < DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) AND
      A.DateOfEntry >= (Select MAX(DateOfEntry) FROM TableA AS D where D.ESource = 'Detail') AND
      A.UnitPrice = (Select MAX(UnitPrice) FROM TableA AS E where E.ESource = 'Detail')
```

Note that the query in your question seems to be missing a `from` clause.  And the condition `C.InvestmentFund = A.InvestmentFun` should be in an `on` clause not in the `where` clause.